# Start handler thread and finish the activity

Tags: java, android

If we start a handler thread / thread in an activity and then the activity is destroyed when we press back button, What happens to the handler thread?

Is it still in running state?

If Yes When the thread execution will stop?

Answer (score 0):

The thread won't be destroyed until its job is finished. So make sure all its job is finished before closing an activity. Because the thread may contain any reference of views and it may try to access it after the job is done. HandlerThread can be stopped by calling

> thread.quitSafely();

this ensures that all pending messages are processed before the thread stops.